# How can I group items in an object if a property is the same?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of objects which looks like this:

- 1,USD,20210101,100
- 1,AUD,20210909,200
- 2,EUR,20200101,200

How can I combine the items if the first property is the same?

Result:

- 1,Multiple
- 2,EUR

I tried the below but doesn't seem to group them.

```
dict
  .GroupBy(x => x.TestId)
  .Where(grp => grp.Select(y => y.TestId).Count() > 1)
  .Select(a => new MyObject{ TestId = a.Key, Currency = a.Count() > 1 ? "Multiple" : a.First().Currency });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this: *doesn't seem to group them*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that `Where`

```
var query = dict
    .GroupBy(x => x.TestId)
    .Select(x => new MyObject{ 
        TestId = g.Key, 
        Currency = g.Count() > 1 ? "Multiple" : g.First().Currency
     });
```